# Why did G-d create everything important off-center?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, eretz-yisrael, science, geography, astronomy

I hope not to argue that the Heliocentric view is true as is our current understanding of [[our position in] the Universe](https://www.buzzfeed.com/daves4/the-universe-is-scary), the Earth is rotating around the Sun, that is rotating around the center of the galaxy, etc.

Our sources speak clearly that the world was created to help us to serve G-d. As we can see, our empirical knowledge goes against **the perception** that we are at the center:

- the Temple isn't in the center of Jerusalem,
- Jerusalem isn't in the center of Israel,
- Israel isn't in the center of the Earth
- Earth isn't in the center of the Solar System,
- The Solar system isn't in the center of the Galaxy,
- Our Galaxy isn't in the center of the cluster etc.

Did G-d reveal the reasons for this structure, and if not, what do the contemporary Rabbis speculate about the possible justifications?

Answer (score 2):

What I recall reading in many places is the word "heart", not "center".  The Holy of Holies is the "heart" of the Temple (not its center).  The Temple is the heart of Jerusalem (not its center), Jerusalem is the heart of Israel, Israel is the heart of the Earth, etc.

Note that your "heart" is not in the "center" of your body.  Neither is your mind.

At any rate, why should the "center" be special?  It's just a geographical location.

I'll look for sources.  Others, please jump in.